# dplyr: conditional filter with character strings as column names

Tags: r, if-statement, filter, dplyr

I am trying to 1) use dplyr::filter with character strings as column names and 2) use if statement, at the same time. However, while either works fine by itself, I had difficulty combining them, seemingly due to the issue that there cannot be a comma in the if statement. Below is a simplified example with dplyr 0.7.1.

Any insights are welcome. Thank you very much!!

```
library("dplyr")

df = data.frame(A=1:6, B=rep(c("good","bad"), 3), C=c("AA","AA","BB","BB","CC","CC"))

# with if statement but not character strings as column names - works
df %>% filter(if(T) {B %in% "good"}) 

# with character string as column names but no if statement - works
df %>% filter_at(vars("B"), any_vars(. %in% "good")) 

# doesn't work when I tried to combine the two
# Error: unexpected ',' in "df %>% filter_at(if(T){vars("B"),"
df %>% filter_at(if(T){vars("B"), any_vars(. %in% "good")})   

# tried to indicate the two parts in the if statement are really one item not two 
# by adding () or {}, and got the same complaint 
df %>% filter_at(if(T){(vars("B"), any_vars(. %in% "good"))}) 
df %>% filter_at(if(T){{vars("B"), any_vars(. %in% "good")}})
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
df %>% filter_at(if(T){vars("B")}, any_vars(. %in% "good"))
```